# Stack Exchange API/users is not available for all stack exchange sites

Tags: api

I am using this link to see all of my own questions as defined by the user id.

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/2040706/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow

But if I try to do it for all of the Joomla! Stack Exchange site it fails.

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/2040706/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=joomla

The site is spelt correctly as you can use it as so

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=joomla

It seems only to be that particular site that is an issue.  Can anyone see anything I'm doing wrong or shed any light on this?  Is it simply that the API does not work on all sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was me being a dimwit.  My user ID is different on each site.

On JSE it is 7164.

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/7164/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=joomla